# Cannot see Author & Monitor card in the Azure Data Factory Overiew page

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created Azure Data Factory account and i can't see author & monitor option where we can do all the ETL stuff.

Please help !

Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the portal doesnt work for you, you can always go to adf.azure.com and login there. You should see your newly created data factory and start working on it!

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it worked when i change the resource group region to Central US